# How to extract all Yahoo emails from a .CSV file?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a CSV file with a lot of email addresses
and i would like to use the grep command to extract
all of the Yahoo emails from the CSV and put them in a new file.

Is this correct : ?

head -10000000 EmailList.csv | grep “@yahoo.com" > file2.csv

Comment: yes,  i tried this in Terminal on my Mac,  but the file2.csv is empty.

Comment: the CSV file looks like this :
“randomemail@yahoo.com”,”Mary”,”Johnson”,”76.20.94.112”,”2014-12-15 04:48:41",

Comment: Do you want to extract the complete line when the line contains an email from `@yahoo.com`? Or do you just want to extract the email address on its own without the rest of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can read directly from a file, so unless you are intentionally trying to limit the input size the use of `head` is unnecessary. Likewise, `cat` is pointless here. The following should work:

```
grep "@yahoo.com" EmailList.csv > file2.csv
```